# Remove Boot Options

Tags: windows, boot, uefi

New to this forum and according to me, there shouldn't be any such problems as having multiple boot entries with windows boot manager.

I am a windows user, and I already had Windows 8.1 installed on the internal HDD and I did install one more Windows 8.1 because I really wanted to make a gap between studying and gaming, and I get diverted from studies, so one OS reserved for studying and study tools or IDE's or whatever, and the second partition was for gaming.

I don't see the necessities of giving out the model of the system or the amount of ram that it has, let me just say that it runs on UEFI and that obviously means GPT. I have legacy enabled, but I wouldn't be using it, since 2 Operating Systems on one drive. Which means UEFI.

Here are the attachments, it's kinda messed up, but I would find both the OS on the first page and it's not a hassle. But it definitely is an inconvenience to see the boot menu cluttered up every morning you wake up. Seriously.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here's the problem: EasyBCD does not show these boot entries in it's `edit boot entry` or `add boot entry`, neither does my firmware settings show em.

Glad if an answer if found and finish this up quickly rather than seeing a lot of clutter every morning I wake.

Thanks.

[image]

This is the result that appears when bcdedit /v is used. There's lots more down there, ask me if ya need it, cause I am too lazy -_-

Comment: Your EasyBCD shows two entries for Windows, the other devices, are not Windows installations so they wouldn’t have BCD entries they are simply your fallback UEFI boot options.  You can probably change the EFI boot order in your firmware settings including removing them as an option

Comment: Well, I mentioned in my question (not in the way you'd expect it to be) that the firmware settings only shows the Windows Boot Manager and no other fallback boot options. If I don't have a choice in the firmware settings, where else would I find to remove these boot options?

Comment: Use a proper boot manager instead. These entries are dynamically generated by the firmware. Or not, in which case removing them could even brick your board.

Comment: Run a Command Prompt that is Run as administrator and enter the command `bcdedit /v`. Is this any different than what you see in EasyBCD?

Comment: I would appreciate it if you could explain it to me more, and by what definition do you mean by a "Proper Boot Manager"?

Comment: @harrymc I get this huge list of Windows Boot Manager and Windows Boot Loader and "Firmware Application" specified with a set of letters and digits like 101fffff.
I'll add the stuff in the question.

Comment: You should be uploading images using the feature provided instead of using a third-party imaging host

Comment: @Ramhound There's a limit prolly like 1Mib and these pics were prolly far more than that. I had already discovered it tho.

Comment: If they are larger then 1 MB then they are likely to large to be helpful.  Let me say this another way, by using a third-party image host other than the one SE has selected, you eliminate the pool of users who can help you.  I can't load that image host from my current location.  It also preserves your images for everyone else, so this question once it's answered, can be used to close similar questions.

Comment: @Ramhound Really sorry, but I cannot really help with that, because every user is limited, and yup it does contain large info

Comment: @DanielB Thanks a lot. Really appreciate it.

Comment: Please don’t use images for text data (like the `bcdedit` output). Instead, copy the text to a code block (triple backtick on an otherwise blank line to start and close).

Comment: @DanielB I did try copying it. Either I am newb or I am pretty sure I would have been able to copy it.

Comment: You can certainly reduce the size of the image by cropping the image. Somebody did it for you so it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

The "Firmware Application" entries are added by the UEFI firmware
and are picked up by Windows. I can also see in your screenshot
many duplicate entries.

It may be that there is ping-pong effect on your computer:
When bcdedit opens the BCD, it compares entries in NVRAM with
entries in BCD.
Entries in NVRAM that were created by the firmware that do not
exist in the BCD are added to the system BCD. When bcdedit
closes the system BCD, any boot manager entries in BCD that
are not in NVRAM are added to NVRAM.
This behavior might result in multiple
firmware entries for the same devices.

I outline below a method for getting rid of the duplicate entries,
at least until they start accumulating again.
This simple script is all that's needed in many cases.

I suggest taking, before starting, a backup image of the *entire* disk.
Do not use Windows Backup for that. I would suggest a third-party
product such as
[AOMEI Backupper Freeware](https://www.ubackup.com/free-backup-software.html).
Create also its
[Bootable CD/DVD/USB Based on Windows PE or Linux](https://www.ubackup.com/features/create-bootable-disc.html)
and test that it can boot and see your system disk and the backup disk.

To delete all EFI boot entries and recreate the two Windows ones,
start a Command Prompt (CMD) as Administrator and enter the
following commands:

```
mountvol U: /s                        (assign letter U to EFI partition)
del /s /f /q U:\efi\*.*               (delete everything under U:\efi)
bcdboot C:\windows /s U: /f UEFI      (rebuild a clean BCD)
bcdboot D:\windows /s U: /f UEFI
mountvol U: /d                        (remove the letter U from the EFI)
```

(Covering note: I have not tried this procedure.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The last part, definitely scary.
Also, do you know someone else who has tried the procedure? If yes, just please let me know.

Comment: Hopefully, a good backup will have you covered.

Comment: I found in a very long post at [this page](https://www.tenforums.com/installation-upgrade/115716-uefi-remove-unwanted-boot-entries-bios-solved-easily-6.html) a similar script that was tested and applauded.